# How to change endian for multi-byte I/O outputs?

Tags: industrial-robot, smartpendant, yaskawa

When using the Yaskawa Smart Pendant SDK API (Java client), it is possible to set multi-byte I/O values via:

```
controller.setOutputGroups(outNum, 2, value16bits);

controller.setOutputGroups(outNum, 4, value32bits);
```

However, sometimes the byte ordering is wrong. Depending on the product vendor or if using Ethernet/IP or IOLink, multi-byte values can be big-endian or little-endian.

How can I swap the ordering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API doesn't have any direct support for endian conversion / byte-swapping.  However, there are some Java functions that can handle it:

```
Short.reverseBytes(short i16)
Integer.reverseBytes(int i32)
Long.reverseBytes(long i64)
```

So, the calls in the question would become:

```
controller.setOutputGroups(outNum, 2, Short.reverseBytes(value16bits));
controller.setOutputGroups(outNum, 4, Integer.reverseBytes(value32bits));
```